# Printing letters in order like a pyramid

Tags: python, programming-challenge, ascii-art, fractals, python-2.x

There is this hackerrank [question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/alphabet-rangoli), where we need a **rhombus of letters**. As to my opinion it can be viewed as some fractal, or similar logic.

Well I solved the question, but I am obviously disappointed with the code I come up with. Actually when I started writing I knew how I would end-up and I was ready to ask a question here.

I am reluctant to share this code of mine but it is necessary, if I am to improve.

```
size = int(raw_input())
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
def draw(size):
    shape = "" # The answer
    tmp_size = size # defining a temporary size variable to help with the solution
    tmp_size -= 1
    while tmp_size+1:
        hyphen_count = (size-tmp_size) *2 - 2 # Needed hyphen count for the left-right of new_line
        hypens = hyphen_count*"-" # Hyphens to be added

        # The new line, the strange ranges I used was to get the correct letters in place. Probably needs simplifying.
        new_line = "-".join([alphabet[abs(num)] for num in range(1-size,tmp_size-size+1) + range(size-tmp_size-1, size)])

        # Draw one line if it is the first line
        if tmp_size == size - 1:
            shape = shape + new_line
        # Draw to both top and bottom if it is not the first line.
        else:
            shape = hypens + new_line + hypens + "\n" + shape + "\n" + hypens + new_line + hypens
        tmp_size -= 1
    return shape
print draw(size)
```

I added many comments for easier evaluation of this badly-written code. So what I ask is:

- Dear users with algorithm experience, please help me find a better method if not the code itself. (Maybe a recursion ?)
- Dear programmers, please help me implement better python.
- Dear users that know everything, please teach me everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose a different method!
If you generate the center, and the size of the shape you can do the entire thing easily with [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

```
>>> '{0:-^16}'.format('yo')
'-------yo-------'
```

Simple.

The biggest problem is getting the diamond shape.
But this can be done with ease.
For the amount of different letters you want per line it goes:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Where the character you want goes:

```
3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3
```

If you make a range that goes like the first, you can change it to the second by subtracting from 4 each time.

I'll define this range as:

```
def piramid_range(size):
    return range(1, size) + range(size, 0, -1)
```

A quick run of size 4 gives us the correct output.
And subtracting from 4 each time gives us the correct output too.

```
>>> piramid_range(4)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> [4 - i for i in piramid_range(4)]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

and so adding this all together, with two comprehensions makes for a nice small function:

```
def draw(size):
    fmt = '{{0:-^{size}}}'.format(size=4 * size - 3)
    return '\n'.join(
        fmt.format('-'.join([alphabet[size - s] for s in piramid_range(inner_size)]))
        for inner_size in piramid_range(size)
    )
```

And finally, as I think your separator character is quite ugly, I think adding the ability to change it would be nice. This is just replacing its two occurrences.

```
def draw(size, char='-'):
    fmt = '{{0:{char}^{size}}}'.format(char=char, size=4 * size - 3)
    return '\n'.join(
        fmt.format(char.join([alphabet[size - s] for s in piramid_range(inner_size)]))
        for inner_size in piramid_range(size)
    )

print draw(4)
print
print draw(4, char=' ')
```

Which would have the following output:

> ```
> ------d------
> ----d-c-d----
> --d-c-b-c-d--
> d-c-b-a-b-c-d
> --d-c-b-c-d--
> ----d-c-d----
> ------d------
>
>       d
>     d c d
>   d c b c d
> d c b a b c d
>   d c b c d
>     d c d
>       d
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Joe Wallis gave a much better algorithm, so I'll just give more general notes.

Instead of defining `alphabet` manually, you could import from the `string` module.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
```

You have a confusing pattern with `tmp_size`. The fact that you have to define `while tmp_size+1` is a red flag. It would be better to write `while tmp_size >= 0`, which gives the same result. But also you don't need to use `while` loops to iterate over a set of numbers. `for i in range(size - 1, -1, -1)` will do what you want.

```
for i in range(size - 1, -1, -1):
```

Now there's no need for `tmp_size`, just refer to `i` as the current size.

You're recreating the string line twice in this line of code:

```
shape = hypens + new_line + hypens + "\n" + shape + "\n" + hypens + new_line + hypens
```

I recommend taking both the hyphen section and the algorithm and moving them to a new function

```
def get_line(i, size):
```

This way it's neater and separated out. You can just call it once to get the current line, then add it to `shape` as necessary.